# Chromecast SDK cast entire screen

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, sdk, chromecast

*I am happy to be redirected if this is not the place to ask this question (I get that).*

Upon looking through resources provided by Google for Chromecast on github, https://github.com/googlecast

I have been unable to find any example of how the "cast entire screen" feature works. I realize that feature is considered 'experimental' and perhaps that is why.

Does the SDK even include that functionality?

I am looking to create a chromecast app that utilizes this feature.

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not exposed through the Cast SDK. You can try [Presentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Presentation.html); I haven't tried that myself but I expect that to work; if it doesn't yet, it probably will in future updates.

Comment: My purpose is in creating a chromecast app that utilizes this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

at Google Cast's extenstion, there is a little arrow at the top right ot it.
Click on it, You'll find "Cast entire screen".